# EWS API Delegate List

Tags: api, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to find a way to get the list of people that I'm a delegate for using the EWS API. I can create and view appointments for the people I'm a delegate for, I just need a way to get the list of who I am a delegate for.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Exchange system administrator can tell you - you can't query EWS for this.

Comment: Is this still the case in the latest version of Exchange? It seems like a useful API that wouldn't be difficult to implement. It'd certainly be useful to me right now!